# How to have multiple sub paths for an API with swagger annotations?

Tags: scala, swagger, spray

When you look on the swagger demo site they have sub paths

[image: swagger demo screenshot]

I am using [swagger-spray](https://github.com/gettyimages/spray-swagger) which happens to use the official [swagger annotations](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-annotations).

When I build my api everything annotated with @Api is grouped into an api entry with a single path.

How within this can I have multiple sub paths such as "/user/login" and "/user/logout"?

Answer (score 2):

It is simple

add @javax.ws.rs.Path("/mysubpath")

For example

```
@Api(value = "/auth", description = "Operations handling authentication")
trait AuthenticationApi {

  val authenticationApiRouting: Route = {
    loginRoute ~ logoutRoute
  }


  @ApiOperation(
    value = "Ends current user session", notes = "Uses cookie",
    nickname = "login",
    httpMethod = "DELETE")
  @ApiImplicitParams(Array(
    new ApiImplicitParam(name = "email", value = "email of user to login", required = false, dataType = "string", paramType = "path")
  ))
  @Path("/logout")
  def logoutRoute = {
    pathPrefix("auth") {
      pathPrefix("logout") {
        pathEndOrSingleSlash {
          get {
            complete {
              <h1>test</h1>
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you end up with this

[image]